# Почему расширение метода String такое медленное?

Tags: javascript, объекты, ecmascript-6

Накидал простенькую функцию по реверсу строки, и потом решил расширить метод объекта String.

```js
// Расширяем стандартный объект
String.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
  'use strict';
  let str = [];

  for (let j = this.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(this.charAt(j));
  }

  return str.join('');
}

// обычная функция
let rev = (data) => {
  let str = [];

  for (let j = data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(data.charAt(j));
  }
  return str.join('');
}
```

Затем решил проверить производительность. Скорость обычной функции выше в 2 раза. Получается правду говорят что лучше не трогать объекты String и Array? Или я неверно сделал что-то?

```js
function generateString(count) {
  let result = '';
  let words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  let max_position = words.length - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    let position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}

console.time('Native')
generateString(5000).reverse()
console.timeEnd('Native')

console.time('Function')
rev(generateString(5000))
console.timeEnd('Function')
```

Comment: Поменяй местами вызовы, и результаты изменятся :-) Проблема в тестировании. Попробуй использовать специализированные инструменты

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую)

Comment: У массива же есть reverse - `str.split('').reverse().join('')` норм работает для ASCII

Comment: У массива есть, а у строки нет. И цель не в том что у кого есть. Просто разбираюсь для себя.

Comment: Ну так и я не ответ писал, а комментарий

Comment: А по теме - зря вы включили генерацию строки внутрь теста. Строка большая - выделение памяти/сборка мусора -> непредсказуемые результаты

Comment: Лучше генерировать, записывать в переменную а потом уже тестить?

Comment: Естественно, тестировать нужно только то, что нужно тестировать. И то не нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнивать операции занимающие доли миллисекунд - бессмысленно.  Понажимайте:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
  'use strict';
  let str = [];

  for (let j = this.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(this.charAt(j));
  }

  return str.join('');
}
let rev = (data) => {
  let str = [];

  for (let j = data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(data.charAt(j));
  }
  return str.join('');
}

function generateString(count) {
  let result = '';
  let words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  let max_position = words.length - 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}

console.time('Native')
generateString(1000000).reverse()
console.timeEnd('Native')

console.time('Function')
rev(generateString(1000000))
console.timeEnd('Function')
```

Comment: Я понимаю. Но почему медленнее?

Comment: @PaulFox Что медленнее?

Comment: Да. Почему расширение медленнее. Я использовал 'use strict'. Без него медленнее в 3-4 раза. С ним - в 2 раза.
П.С. почему-то тут почти равное время. У меня же на codepen в 2 раза медленнее.

Comment: @PaulFox, сниппет показывает примерно одинаковые результаты же.

Comment: Странно но не везде. В codepen по другому, как и в редакторе

Comment: @PaulFox, что еще раз доказывает, что тесты могут быть не совсем корректны.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не всегда одинаковые :-) попробуй страницу например обновить, а потом несколько раз понажимать

Comment: @Grundy, тут строка генерится половину времени. Отличный тест, ага

Comment: Спасибо. Codepen - кривой оказался. Давно за этой песочницей подмечал косяки. Но не думал что на таком простом тесте будут нестыковки там

Answer (score 0):

Демонстрация бессмысленности подобного тестирования(и немножко более корректный сниппет):

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
  'use strict';
  let str = [];

  for (let j = this.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(this.charAt(j));
  }

  return str.join('');
}

let rev2 = function(s) {
  let i, o;
  for (i = s.length - 1, o = ''; i >= 0; o += s[i--]);
  return o;
}

let rev = (data) => {
  let str = [];

  for (let j = data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    str.push(data.charAt(j));
  }
  return str.join('');
}

function generateString(count) {
  let result = '';
  let words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  let max_position = words.length - 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
    result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
  }
  return result;
}

let source = generateString(10000), iters;

iters = 1000;
console.time('Function')
while(--iters) rev(source)
console.timeEnd('Function')

iters = 1000;
console.time('Native')
while(--iters) source.reverse()
console.timeEnd('Native')

iters = 1000;
console.time('Function 2') 
while(--iters) rev(source)
console.timeEnd('Function 2') // Уже лучше!

iters = 1000;
console.time('Native 2')
while(--iters) source.reverse()
console.timeEnd('Native 2')

iters = 1000;
console.time('yet another')
while(--iters) rev2(source)
console.timeEnd('yet another')
```

Всё очень сильно зависит от выделения/освобождения памяти.
Результаты по сути не зависят от используемой функции, если функции одинаковы.

А вот `rev2` очевидно показывает лучшие результаты ;)

Comment: Причину я выяснил, но у Вас ошибка в rev 2. Разница между этим способом(str[i]) и charAt заключается в том, что если символа нет – charAt выдает пустую строку, а скобки – undefined:
Хотя это не ошибка как таковая.

Comment: Пример входной строки, вызывающей ошибку в студию.

Comment: Я не спорить сюда пришел, а учиться/набираться опыта/находить ответы на вопросы, так что не понимаю такой реакции
Вот пример
console.log( "".charAt(0) ); // пустая строка
console.log( "" [0] ); // undefined

Comment: Какой такой реакции? Мне же интересно, где ошибка. По моему в rev2 просто негде взяться некорректному индексу, чтобы получить эту ошибку

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо! Вопрос решился благодаря подсказке - **Grundy**.

При локальном тестировании результаты примерно равны. *'use strict'*- не забываем про него, когда расширяем стандартный объект своим методом. У меня по крайней мере с ним быстрее.